# How to find something where contains in JSON

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions")
public class Permission {

    public Permission(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Version
    private int version;


    @JsonIgnore
    @Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
    @Column(name = "sub_category", columnDefinition = "json")
    private List<Integer> subCategory = new ArrayList<>();

    .
    .
    .


    <Setter Getter>
    ....
```

and I store a list of integer to database as `JSON Type` like this.

`[349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365]` as JSON and I am using MYSQL.

I need to find to all permission is contains in this list.

for example: 
I have 10 rows of `permission`, how can i find `350` where already exist in some row.

if i am doing a query in mysql, maybe something like this.

`select * from permission where JSON_SEARCH(sub_category,'$[*]') = 350`

entitManager.createQuery("Select g from Permission ")

Comment: Does the SQL query work? And if yes you can just use it with createNativeQuery

Comment: @SimonMartinelli no, that NativeQuery is just a sample to show what i want to do.

Comment: Aha but JSON_SEARCH is not available in JPA. So the SQL would be perfectly fine

Comment: @SimonMartinelli can you show me the example?

Comment: I'm confused you posted the example: select * from permission where JSON_SEARCH(sub_category,'$[*]') = 350

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it just a sample to show you what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solusion for this problem.

I use a query like this.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT permissions.*
FROM permissions, JSON_TABLE(sub_category, "$[*]" COLUMNS(nr INT PATH '$')) as ids  where ids.nr  = 349;
```

this query will help you to find where `349` is in `JSON` with value `[123,349,350,452,344,67,676,2,4,666,7334,4353453,65,56,745]`

> **NOTE:** This query just work on Mysql Version 8.x